# How to set checkbox property in a group of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, setvalue

in the following snippet, I want (from a group of checkboxes) to disable the correspondent check button:

```
var leftradios  = "input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaionCode1']";
var rightradios = "input[name='ctlC1$rblPositionCodfde2']";
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
   if ($(leftradios)[i].checked) {
   $(rightradios)[i].prop('disabled', true); //<--- this should be the culprit
}
```

What is wrong with the last line? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace it with

```
$(rightradios).eq(i).prop('disabled', true);
```

square brackets accesses the array like object and gets the native DOM node, not the jQuery object, and the native DOM node has no `prop` method.

Another option would be

```
$(rightradios)[i].disabled = true;
```